# What is the best way to prefetch relations for model object? (non-lazy loading)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a models

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    first_name: DS.attr('string')
    });


App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
    language: DS.belongsTo('App.Language')
    });

App.Language = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
    });
```

What is the proper way to get a Language for user in controller?
For example I want to save an Item and set language to current user language.

```
var lang = currentUser.get('profile').get('language')
App.Album.createRecord({
        'name': data.get('name'),
        'language': null
    });
```

It's fails first time. But if i call 
    currentUser.get('profile').get('language')
next time - it will show result.

Is there something like Non-Lazy load or prefetch?
To make

```
var lang = currentUser.get('profile').get('language')
```

work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Sideloading. This is covered in the Ember guides: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do with some observers or bindings?

Comment: @lurii, if your server can't serve back multiple records at once, then there's not way we can manage this without multiple requests. On the client we can't tell which request to make next without resolving the first one. While I still think sideloading is the best solution here, the next best solution is to observe the language name and delay creation of the album until the language has been fetched from the server.